# Using javascript ES6 code generated with babeljs.io and webpack in a custom framework

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm developing a module that needs to be implemented into a custom js framework. I have written all my code for the module in ES6 and im using webpack and babel to minify and convert code into old school js.

In the framework's description it says that all modules must start with the code below.

```
(function(){

function main(platform, element)
{
    alert('Hello World!');

}

return main;})();
```

I've tried to convert this to ES6 myself, with no luck:

```
class main{

    constructor(platform, element){

        console.log('');

    }
}

new main();
```

Please let me know if you see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The framework is expecting a function it can call with two arguments, you're giving it a class instance whose constructor arguments you didn't pass.

Comment: That makes sense thanks. So would the correct code look like this?

    class Game{

    constructor(){
      Return this.main;
    }

main(platform, element){}

}

new Game();